# How to get the field from interact in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript I defined a interface like this:

```
export interface getConversationItemAction {
    type: 'CONVERSATION_NAME';
    data: any;
}
```

Is it possible to get the `CONVERSATION_NAME` without initialing the interface? like `getConversationItemAction.type`. I have tried to define a const like this:

```
export const GET_CONVERSATION_NAME_TYPE = 'CONVERSATION_NAME';

export interface getConversationItemAction {
    type: GET_CONVERSATION_NAME_TYPE;
    data: any;
}
```

It seems did not work. I want to use the same type name reference with the whole project without initial everywhere. I also tried like this:

```
type myDataType = conversationItemAction['type'];
console.log("type:", String(myDataType));
```

still could not work, tell that `'myDataType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`.

Comment: It sound like it is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface does not exist during runtime, so it's not possible to access without having an object during runtime. If you wish to access this value, it must exist during runtime. It needs to be initialized.

You could, however, try using an enum for this as these do exist during runtime.

```
export enum ConversationItemActionType {
  CONVERSATION_NAME: "CONVERSATION_NAME"
}
```